# Could the divergences in loop Feynman diagrams be resolved by applying an exponentially decreasing probability eg fluctuation theorem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, singularities, regularization

Since the divergence originates from having to integrate over an infinite range of intermediate energies, surely the bigger the temporary energy delta, the less likely it will be, and the shorter the duration of the intermediate stage can be by the uncertainty principle. Is this already factored in to the calculation and insufficient to produce convergence? Or if not, why is it not relevant?

Comment: The uncertainty principle is already built in. But you could damp the large momenta with $\exp(-\alpha p^2)$ and keep the fintie part as $\alpha \to 0$ as a form of regularization. You could also keep $\alpha$ non-zero to describe certain theories with nonlocal propagators.